# Put a string as hex inside a Uint32_t

Tags: c

I would like to get this result :

```
static uint32_t const m_deadbeef = 0x4c414c41 ; //this hex is "LALA"
```

from this input :

```
char data[]="LALA";
```

So I need to put `data` inside the `unint32_t` so it looks like the first line.
How would I do it efficiently ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is trivial, you just need to grab the character values and combine them:

```
uint32_t uint_from_string(const char *s)
{
  uint32_t x = 0;
  for (int i = 0; *s != '\0' && i < 4; ++i)
  {
    x <<= 8;
    x |= (uint32_t) *s++;
  }
  return x;
}
```

If you use this like so:

```
const uint32_t m_deadbeef = uint_from_string("LALA");
```

you will get the value `0x4c414c41` in there.

Also, *please note* that there is no "putting as hex" going on here, the number just as well be printed in decimal (it's `1279347777`). Numbers are not in hex, only their representation when printed out.

Comment: That seems great, but for some reason when trying to call the method the compiler says :  conflict types of  uint_from_string. Not sure why but it's running on a small ARM chip.

Comment: @Curnelious You need to put the function before the `main` or try to put the function prototype `uint32_t uint_from_string(const char *s)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

union str32b
{
    uint32_t hex;
    char str[4];

    str32b(const char* in, int big_end = 0)
    {
        if (big_end)
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
                str[i] = in[i];
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
                str[4 - i - 1] = in[i];
    }
};

int main()
{
    const char* input = "ABCD";

    str32b l_end = str32b(input);
    printf("Little endian:\t0x%x\n", l_end.hex);

    str32b b_end = str32b(input, 1);
    printf("Big endian:\t0x%x\n", b_end.hex);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Little-endian:  0x41424344
Big-endian:     0x44434241
```